# Fastest way to downcast an array short to char

Tags: c++, performance

I have to process roughly 2000, 100 element arrays every second. The arrays come to me as shorts, w/ the data in the upper bits and need to be shifted and cast to chars. Is this as efficient as I can get, or is there a faster way to perform this operation? (I have to skip 2 of the values)

```
for(int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
{
    a[i] = (char)(b[i] >> 8);
    a[i+48] = (char)(b[i+50] >> 8);
}
```

Comment: What does your benchmarking tell you? If you're not benchmarking you're going to be shooting in the dark here. Bit-shifting an 8-bit value 8 bits seems broken.

Comment: I assume, you mean `(char)(b[i] >> 8);`

Comment: That code won't work as expected, because casting has higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the shift operation.

Comment: @sergeya yup, typed instead of copied.

Comment: Instead of bit shifting why not just recast the source as `char` and pull out the values you want directly? Just make sure you get your endian code correct

Comment: @tadman, you can't - it is not specified whether this casting retains high or low octet. On big endians, it would retain low octet.

Comment: You cast the `short[100]` to a `char*` and work on the raw bytes.  This of course requires knowing how `short`s are laid out in the particular environment.

Comment: @SergeyA If you're really desperate for speed, reinterpreting the array of shorts as an array of chars would make things a lot easier. Of course, this would require knowing your architecture and getting the right byte out.

Comment: Agree with @tadman. Fastest way is to cast to array of bytes (standard-conforming operation) and than pick the bytes you want. The only problem is that this is going to be endian-dependent, and there is no portable way to figure your endianness.

Comment: So, I tried doing the cast, method, but it required having two tracking variables, one for array a index and one for b index, and it seemed that the shift was faster than having to inc -- now i didn't profile it as an isolated piece of code, so I could be wrong in that.

Comment: "The arrays come to me as shorts" - why? Fix the cause, then the symptom goes away.

Comment: have to play by other people's interfaces :\

Comment: The recast approach should see your index incrementing by 2, no 1. I'm not sure how that'd end up being slower. The `b` index is always `i*2+1` if your offset is 1, or just `i*2` if there's no offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if shift and bitwise operation are fast, you can try to process the short array as a char pointer as other advised in comments. It is allowed per standard and for common architectures does what is expected - left the endianness problem.

So you could try to first determine your endianness:

```
bool isBigEndian() {
    short i = 1;   // sets only lowest order bit
    char *ix = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&i);
    return (*ix == 0);   // will be 1 if little endian
}
```

Your loop now becomes:

```
int shft = isBigEndian()? 0 : 1;
char * pb = reinterpret_cast<char *>(b);
for(int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
{
    a[i] = pt[2 * i + shft];
    a[i+48] = pt[2 * i + 50 + shft];
}
```

But as always for low level optimisation, this has to be benchmarked with the compiler and compiler options that will be used in production code.

Comment: I'll try both out and time them. Thanks.

Comment: testing seems to show that the new loop is 10% faster : )

Comment: probably will also speed up to make the big-endian decision at compile time

Comment: @M.M., how would you do this?

Comment: I'd use `#define` to a value determined using knowledge of the target.  (Apparently it's not possible to determine endianness via `constexpr`).

Comment: @M.M: Of course you can use defines, and it is the way to go if you use tools such as autoconf. But if you have just a makefile, just have to either use `make big` // `make little`, or pray for never forget to change the damned define...

Comment: @M.M: [GNU C lets you do](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) `#if __BYTE_ORDER__ == __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__`, for example.  Or in this case, use a variation on that `==` expression as a replacement for `isBigEndian`, no `#if` needed.  This unfortunately isn't ISO standard C or C++, though.

Comment: @pyInTheSky: [gcc already compiles the code in the question to byte loads and byte stores](https://godbolt.org/g/NHpxFS) (same code as in my answer, but with `#undef __SSE2__` to get the C fallback.  There's no shifting in the asm.  (It uses `movsx eax, [mem]` to avoid false dependencies; note that the stores are just byte stores from from `al`).  However, with `-O3`, gcc [auto-vectorizes with really messy code](https://godbolt.org/g/1KqZih).  It unpacks to 32bit elements, and uses arithmetic shifts but then masks off the high half...  better check the asm from your compiler + options).

Answer (score 1):

You could put a wrapper class around these arrays, so code that accesses elements of the wrapper in order *actually* accesses every other byte of the underlying memory.

This will probably defeat auto-vectorization, though.  Other than that, having all the code that would read `a` actually read `b` and increment its pointers by two instead of one shouldn't change the cost at all.

The two skipped elements are a problem, though.  Having your `operator[]` do `if (i>=48) i+=2` might kill this idea.  `memmove` will often be *much* faster than storing one byte at a time, so you could consider using `memmove` to make a contiguous array of shorts that you can index even though it seems silly to copy without storing in a better format.

The trick will be to write a wrapper that completely optimizes away to no extra instructions in loops over your arrays.  This is possible on x86, where scaled indexing is available in normal effective-addresses in asm instructions, so if the compiler understands what's going on, it can make code that's just as efficient.

Having arrays of `short`s does take twice as much memory, so cache effects could matter.

It all depends on what you need to do with the byte arrays.

---

#### If you do need to convert, use SIMD

For x86 targets, you can get a big speedup with SIMD vectors instead of looping one char at a time.  For other compile targets you care about, you can write similar special versions.  I assume ARM NEON has similar shuffling capability, for example.

When writing a platform-specific version, you also get to make all the endian and unaligned-access assumptions that are true on that platform.

```
#ifdef __SSE2__  // will be true for all x86-64 builds and most i386 builds
#include <immintrin.h>
static __m128i pack2(const short *p) {
    __m128i lo = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)p);
    __m128i hi = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)(p + 8));
    lo = _mm_srli_epi16(lo, 8);         // logical shift, not arithmetic, because we need the high byte to be zero
    hi = _mm_srli_epi16(hi, 8);
    return _mm_packus_epi16(lo, hi);    // treats input as signed, saturates to unsigned 0x0 .. 0xff range
}
#endif // SSE2

void conv(char *a, const short *b) {
#ifdef __SSE2__
    for(int i = 0; i < 48; i+=16) {
        __m128i low  = pack2(b+i);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)(a+i), low);
        __m128i high = pack2(b+i + 50);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)(a+i + 48), high);
    }
#else
    /*******   Fallback C version  *******/
    for(int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
        a[i] = (char)(b[i] >> 8);
        a[i+48] = (char)(b[i+50] >> 8);
    }
#endif
}
```

[As you can see on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-Wall+-Wextra+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-fverbose-asm+-O3+-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops+-march%3Dhaswell+-mno-avx',sourcez:MQSwZgJgpmAED68DKSCiAmRtYHoewHcQAbY2AIylgBcAnAVyrAHtbYBDU2ADwA4A2ALT8ALBXokIAZw4A7CLAC2zKdVggAzAPGSpAKFCyAxsXrRYAHhCLFIWXTsA6ABYA%2BPavbUQRhPEUAjOi8ILAADuxGANboABRGzLKqsFLOrGoAVGEAlLAA3nrY2IiBwaHEzLAAvAg28BXsEPTwUiBBvLGxJe0gGdk5ANyFRd1lsM6hNf6K9cyNza3tnaMhfbFhsADUsLzZ2UNFsBXVtTNStMQg8FBhbfyxFQA0O/vD2BMn0y0XVzd3sRNnrsDkVaFBqPRaLJTvAItF6FJrrcAvcnuMQK8AL4GKDycC4fAoDB6PQAN2YIAUCVkpPiznYbAyiDBqloPmoWHYz2pyVS6VgTPgLIcRg58AouQKoEgMD8RMw8DesBYtFidjUk1gAAYBupLLARLxdSBNlUUZKlYcVuVmARsDU4TFYuRNhiQYdinVVKwoAs2sFlv4egLsrF2K7ss8KgRXh6RkGxhMAObOE6OuIu0LbACsWtjcZh3rBfqWXQTIRDYddWwNu2eyec%2Bew2OAUGIUigSpwGR7vYyRQAYpxiORIlFYABhWCkqC0VqJbB93s4JUqtX2PU1HV6iy142bTYWgscADaIAAuic6QzQ%2BQz5fXK4Xu6Pewz5tDZeatfaLf37mHyfYElRbXEIHAPRMSAAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), gcc fully unrolls the loop since it's only a few iterations when storing 16B at a time.

This should perform ok, but on pre-Skylake will bottleneck on shifting both vectors of `short`s before the store.  Haswell can only sustain one `psrli` per clock.  (Skylake can sustain one per 0.5c when the shift-count is an immediate.  See Agner Fog's guide and insn tables, links at the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)

You might get better results from loading from `(__m128i*)(1 + (char*)p)` so the bytes we want are already in the low half of each 16bit element.  We'd still have to mask off the high half of each element with `_mm_and_si128` instead of shifting, but `PAND` can run on any vector execution port, so it has three per clock throughput.

More importantly, with AVX it can be combined with an unaligned load.  e.g. `vpand  xmm0, xmm5, [rsi]`, where xmm5 is a mask of `_mm_set1_epi16(0x00ff)`, and `[rsi]` holds `2*i + 1 + (char*)b`.  fused-domain uop throughput is probably going to be an issue, like is common for code with a lot of loads/stores as well as computation.

Unaligned accesses are slightly slower than aligned accesses, but at least half your vector accesses will be unaligned anyway (since skipping two shorts means skipping 4B).  On Intel SnB-family CPUs, I don't think it's slower to have loads that are split across a cache-line boundary in a 15:1 split compared to a 12:4 split.  (The no-split case is definitely faster, though.)  If `b` is 16B-aligned, then it'll be worth testing the mask version against the shift version.

I didn't write up complete code for this version, because you'll end up reading one byte past the end of `b` unless you take special precautions.  This is fine if you make sure `b` has padding of some sort so it doesn't go right to the end of a memory page.

---

#### AVX2

With AVX2, `vpackuswb ymm` operates in two separate lanes.  IDK if there's anything to gain from doing the load and mask (or shift) on 256b vectors and then using a `vextracti128` and 128b pack on the two halves of the 256b vector.

Or maybe do a 256b pack between two vectors and then a `vpermq` (`_mm256_permute4x64_epi64`) to sort things out:

```
lo = _mm256_loadu(b..);  // { b[15..8]  | b[7..0] }
hi =                     // { b[31..24] | b[23..16] }

// mask or shift
__m256i packed = _mm256_packus_epi16(lo, hi);    // [ a31..24  a15..8 | a23..16  a7..0 ]
packed = _mm256_permute4x64_epi64(packed, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 2, 0));
```

---

Of course, use any portable optimizations you can in the C version.  e.g. Serge Ballesta's suggestion of just copying the desired bytes after figuring out their location from the endianness of the machine.  (Preferably at compile time by checking [GNU C's `__BYTE_ORDER__` macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).