# Pack (with saturation) __m256i of 16-bit values to __m128i of 8-bit values?

Tags: x86, simd, avx, avx2

Is there an AVX or AVX2 operation to convert `__m256i` of 16x16-bit unsigned int (uint16_t) values to `__m128i` of 16x8-bit unsigned int (uint8_t) values (**taking lower bytes with saturation**)?

There is `_mm256_packus_epi16()` but it uses first 8 bytes from first input, then first 8 bytes from second input, and then second 8 bytes from first and second input... resulting in groups of 8 bytes being out of order.

There are also some AVX512 ops that seems to do what's needed, but i can't depend on AVX512, it's not present on many target machines...

Comment: Can `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` or another shuffling op fix the order afterwards?

Comment: I think you mean `__m256i`.   `__m256` is a vector of single-precision floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not do that in a single instruction with AVX/AVX2.

> There is _mm256_packus_epi16() but it uses first 8 bytes from first input, then first 8 bytes from second input, and then second 8 bytes from first and second input... resulting in groups of 8 bytes being out of order.

Here's how you can arrange it properly (AVX2):

```
static inline __m128i convert(__m256i data) {
  __m128i lo_lane = _mm256_castsi256_si128(data);
  __m128i hi_lane = _mm256_extracti128_si256(data, 1);
  return _mm_packus_epi16(lo_lane, hi_lane);
}
```

According to [uops.info](https://www.uops.info/table.html) on Skylake `_mm256_extracti128_si256` is 1 µop on p5 and `_mm_packus_epi16` is 1 µop on p5. That means throughput of this code block should be 2 cycles (one conversion every two cycles).

You could target AVX by using `_mm256_extractf128_si256`. It's possible that it would cost additional latency for domain-crossing (but throughput should be the same AFAIK).

Comment: Fantastic!! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov: if you have a lot of data to handle this way, it's usually best to use `_mm256_packus_epi16` on 2 inputs, then `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` to fix up the mess created by the craptastic AVX2 in-lane pack.  2 shuffles for one 32-byte vector is clearly better than 4 shuffles for two 16-byte vectors like you'd get from this (except on AMD Zen1 where `vextracti128` is super cheap, and lane-crossing 256-bit shuffles are expensive)

Comment: My answer on [Fastest way to downcast an array short to char](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36413810) shows how to use pack + vpermq fixup on a pair of `__m256i` 16x 16-bit to get one `__m256i` 32x 8-bit in the right order.